# Density map based on polygon layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, density

I have a polygon shapefile representing a certain feature (e.g. irrigated crops) over a study area. I want to produce a density map for irrigated crops based on a reference square grid (e.g. 1X1 km). In other words, I want to know how many hectares of irrigated crops are present within every cell of the square grid.

I use ArcMap.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to an ArcGIS Advanced licence, you could use the Tabulate Intersection tool in the Analysis->Statistics toolbox to calculate the area of irrigated crops per 1x1km grid cell.  For this to work you need to ensure that the crop layer has an area field (which you will use as the Sum Fields option in the TI tool) and that each reference grid cell has a unique ID, which you will use to join the resulting table of the Tabulate Intersection process to the original reference grid. Then after joining the resulting table with the reference grid  you can symoblize the reference grid by Quantities.